# regular expression content-type

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net madam in my application and I want to check switch to basic authentication based on content-type requested. But only way to add discriminator is through regular expression and I am very poor in regular expressions, Can anyone help me write a regular expression which checks whether string is either "application/json" or "application/xml" in regular expression.

Comment: What's ASP.NET madam? :O I want to use her too! :)

Comment: So, wait, do you want to auth differently for json vs xml, or for (either json or xml) vs something else (presumably html)?

Comment: The extended regex `^application/(json|xml)$` will match the cases you have.  Depending on context, you may not want the `^...$` anchors.  Not familiar with ASP.NET so not sure if this needs to be quoted or backslash-escaped somehow (or whether it supports extended regular expressions at all).

Comment: I highly doubt regular expressions are the only way. If you don't understand regular expressions, you only want to check for those two types and this isn't ultra high performance code, a simple string comparison may be clearer and more maintainable. Optimize it later.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple regular expression to match it:

```
^application/(json|xml)$
```

If you don't have clear that the string is at the beginning and end of the line, just:

```
application/(json|xml)
```

And if you need to escape the / bar:

```
application\/(json|xml)
```

You may even need not to capture the json|xml expression, so you can do:

```
application\/(?:json|xml)
```